# Git usage issue on Colab

Tags: git, ubuntu, installation, google-colaboratory, torch

I'm trying to use customised install scripts for Torch on Google Colab.

I've run into an issue with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git fetch
git reset --hard
# Submodule update is done inside install.sh
/root/torch/install.sh -s
```

Colab reports this to the git commands:

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` means you attempted to run a Git command but weren’t inside a Git repository.

The first command `git fetch` will fetch branches and/or tags  from one or more other repositories, so the script should be placed inside a git repo.

Be sure that you are in a git repo, do a `git status` or `git remote -v` to check if you're in a repo folder.

You can invoke shell commands in Colab using either `!` or `%%shell` in your cell : `!pwd` or `!git status`